# What is the song in My hero academia season 4 episode 83 played at 23:48 during the preview

Tags: my-hero-academia

What is the song in My hero academia season 4 episode 83 played at 23:48 during the preview

It also appears somewhere during the middle of the episode

Answer (score 0):

The song is called 士傑と雄英 ("Shiji and Yuhide" per Google Translate) by Yuki Hayashi. You can find the song on Spotify [here](https://open.spotify.com/track/0xBikjBWKqN9Mh5OQ7n0y4?si=zGNIO5bOTPWuZW_ZtmbcAg).